# How to set cronExpression programatically using javacode for Quartz Scheduler with Spring?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

BackGround :

I am using Quartz scheduler with Spring to schedule a cronjob.

Question:

I am configuring the scheduler options in my applicationconfig file. Rather, I want to specify these options programatically in my java class. Any ideas on how to achieve this? 
My Code is as below,

ApplicationConfig

```
<!-- Cron Trigger -->
<bean id="SimpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="TaskJobDetail" />
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 19 14 * * ?" />  
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
 <property name="jobDetails">
    <list>
    <ref bean="TaskJobDetail" />
    </list>
</property>  
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
    <ref bean="SimpleTrigger" />
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

I want to set the cronExpression programatically in my java class. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you first have to inject the Quartz scheduler to your Java class (Spring bean):

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;
```

Then simply use [Quartz API](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3):

```
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*:

JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class).build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 19 14 * * ?"))
    .build();

schedulder.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom,When I am using the above code, it asks me to create newJob(),newMethod method. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @Gendaful: yes, you need some static imports, see my updates answer. Not sure if the list is complete, look at the Quartz documentation linked for a reference.

Comment: Will this job work after server restart or we need run this code again?